# How to place author names in two different columns?

Tags: two-column, multicol, author

I have taken the following from a [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/11-785-project-proposal-template/gvfmxtrwcttd):

[image: template]

However, I want the author names to be placed in two different columns to avoid leaving so much white space in the document. I tried using `\multicols` but the `\columnbreak` does not work with the `\author{}` section. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Here is the relevant code:

```
\author{
Alice Foo \\
\texttt{foo@andrew.cmu.edu} \\
\AND
Bob Bar \\
\texttt{bar@andrew.cmu.edu} \\
\AND
Carl Baz \\
\texttt{baz@andrew.cmu.edu}
\AND
Dan Waldo \\
\texttt{waldo@andrew.cmu.edu}
}
```

and all the packages being used in the template:

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{11785_project,times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
```

**Update:** By using smaller `\and` I was able to get two columns but the formatting and spacing is incorrect. Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Hi, please provide a compilable MWE. At least, one needs to know which `documentclass` you're using, since many redefine the `author` command.

Comment: That is not an MWE. Please, provide in your question a complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Thoughts}
\author{% enter a tabular-like environment
Alice Foo \\
\texttt{foo@andrew.cmu.edu} \\ \\
Carl Baz \\
\texttt{baz@andrew.cmu.edu}
\and % switch to a new column
Bob Bar \\
\texttt{bar@andrew.cmu.edu} \\ \\
Dan Waldo \\
\texttt{waldo@andrew.cmu.edu} \\ \\
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!